# Making a function that builds a dataframe

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to make a function that basically builds a dataframe and returns it. This new dataframe is made of columns taken from another dataframe that I have, called `metadata`.. in addetion to some additional data that I want to control, by passing the TRUE or FALSE values when calling the function.

Here is what I did:

```
make_data = function(metric, use_additions = FALSE){
  
  data = data.frame(my_metric = metadata[['metric']], gender = metadata$Gender , 
                    age = as.numeric(metadata$Age) , use_additions = t(additional_data))
  data = data %>% dplyr::select(my_metric, everything())
  return(data)
}

data = make_data(CR, FALSE)
```

I want to pass different `metric` values each time, and all other features stay the same. So here for example I called the function with metric as `CR` which is the name of the column I want in the metadata. The argument I want to control is `use_additions`, sometines I want to add it and sometimes I don't.

`metadata` and `additional_data` have the exact same row names and the same rows number. It's just adding the data or not.

I get this error(s):

```
Error in data.frame(metric = metadata[["metric"]], gender = metadata$Gender,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1523
In addition: Warning message:
In data.frame(metric = metadata[["metric"]], gender = metadata$Gender,  :
 
Error in data.frame(my_metric = metadata[["metric"]], gender = metadata$Gender, :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1523
```

I've tried several ways to do this, with `''` and without, using the `$`, but non of these worked. So for example when I type `metric = metadata[[metric]]` I get this:

```
Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x, :
object 'CR' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    make_data = function(colname, use_additions = FALSE){
  
  data = data.frame(my_metric = metadata[colname], gender = metadata$Gender , 
                    age = as.numeric(metadata$Age))
  if (use_additions) data$use_additions=additional_data
  return(data)
}

data = make_data(“CR”, FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I make the `colname`, be also the column name in the new data frame? Hence if I enter the `colname` as CR for example, the column name in the new data frame would be  `CR` and not `colname`..